# Can I write an if else statement in one line in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, shortcut

I'm not talking about the ternary operator. Can I write an if else statement in one line outside of a value expression? I want to shorten this code.

```
if x == 'A':
    return True
if x == 'B':
    return True
if x == 'C':
    return True
return False
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to combine all the lines into one if statement?

Comment: @Remolten No, I'd just like to write the `return True` statements in the same line of their corresponding if statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator like this:

```
return x in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

For [Python 3.2+](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations):

```
return x in {'A', 'B', 'C'}
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations):

> Python’s peephole optimizer now recognizes patterns such x in `{1, 2, 3}`
>   as being a test for membership in a set of constants. The optimizer
>   recasts the `set` as a `frozenset` and stores the pre-built constant.
>
> Now that the speed penalty is gone, it is practical to start writing
>   membership tests using set-notation.

Answer (score 5):

You can shorten your code by using [`in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
return x in ("A", "B", "C")
```

Or, if `x` is a single character:

```
return x in "ABC"
```

Answer (score 4):

If your checks are more complicated than membership in a set and you want to reduce the number of lines of code, you can use [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
return True if x == 'A' else True if x == 'B' else True if x == 'C' else False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to apply the same test for many items in a sequence, you may want to use the `any` function:

```
return any(x == c for c in "ABC")
```

This will work for tests that are more complex that equality (so that `in` can't handle them) and for sequences that are too long for chained conditional expressions. Consider a "near equality" test for floating point numbers:

```
return any(abs(x - n) < epsilon for n in big_sequence_of_floats)
```